# Speed type game in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I'm a student with a small school project. For the project, I chose to do a typing speed test game. I already did most of the work, but I can't figure out how can I code so that the program detects when a wrong letter has been typed in. I would like it to be as simple as possible, with no need for anything special. Thanks in advance!

Here is a part of the script.

```
            timer = window.setInterval(function(){
                if (done==false){
                    vrijeme++;
                    $('#time').html('Vrijeme: ' + vrijeme);
                }
                else{
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
            }, 1000);
            
            var textran = $("#tekst").html();
            $('#ulaz').on('keyup', function (){
                $("textarea").each(function(){
                    var textar= $('textarea').val();
                    if (textran == textar){
                        var wps= (brojsl/timer).toFixed(2);
                        var wpm= (brojsl/(timer/60)).toFixed(2);
                        alert('Pisali ste brzinom: ' + wps + ' riječi po sekundi');
                        alert('Pisali ste brzinom: ' + wpm + ' riječi po minuti');
                        clearInterval(timer);
                    }
                });

            });
```

Comment: Wrong letter based on what criteria?

Comment: @charlietfl based on the source `if (textran == textar){`

Comment: A suggestion: you know how far they have got, based on `textar.length` so you can use `textran.slice(0, textar.length) == textar` to see if they've made any mistakes *so far* then provided an indicator (eg red border in the input)

Comment: Off topic: you probably want `var textran = $("#tekst").text().trim();` otherwise you get whitespace within `<div id=textran>` and any markup (there probably won't be any, but better to use the correct method)

Comment: More suggestions: Using `if (textran == textar){` means it won't end until it's 100% correct.  You could perhaps use `if (textran.length == textar.length){` to end the typing part then check if it's the same / how many errors there were.   You could also add an indicator on the source `#tekst` to show which character they're currently on and if any where previous errors.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for the advice, will try when I am able to access my PC.

Comment: @freedomn-m It works perfectly! Could you post your first, suggestion comment as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you store everything the user types into a string and have the 'master' string that has the full correct string, you can use a library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-similarity) to do this in one line.

`var percent = stringSimilarity.compareTwoStrings("Stack Overflow","Stack Ovfwr");` will return you a decimal that you can use as a percent.